# Make div stretch to height of content, not height of page

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a 100% height:

```
height: 100%;
```

Plus I added an absolute position:

```
position: absolute;
```

When I added the absolute position property, the div stretches to the height of the page instead of the height of the content inside it like before. How can I make it so the div stretches to the height of the content, not the page?

Here is the full code if that helps at all:

```
.blah {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute; 
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px; 
    border: 0px solid .800000;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow:  1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: Remove the `height:100%` it will by default take the content height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just don't use `height:100%` and the height will be automatically adjusted to the content.

The behaviour you describe stems from the fact that the parent element - according to which the 100% are determined - becomes the `body` element once you assign `position:absolute;` (assuming you didn't position other parent elements of that DIV).

Comment: Wow that was dumb of me! That must have ended up there because I pasted the code from another project.